# Change of Variables in triple integrals

Tags: integration

there is a region bounded by $x=1$ and $y=2$ on the sides, by $z=3$ below and by the plane $x+y+z=10$ above.
I want to calculate the function $y$ over this region, so I've written and solved the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_{3}^7 \left(\int_{2}^{9-z} \left(\int_{1}^{10-y-z}y\,dx\right)\,dy\right)dz=32
\end{equation}
However I was wondering if I could simplify the problem with a change of variable. I'm really not sure about how to do it, I know the formula, however the result that I get is very different. 
My change of variable was $x'=x-1$, $y'=y-2$, $z'=z-3$.

I got the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^4\int_0^{4-z'}\int_0^{4-y'-z'}y'-2\, dx\,dy\,dz \neq 32
\end{equation}
Why I do not get the same answer? I've changed the function from $y$ to $y'-2$ and I've calculated the determinant of the Jacobian, which is 1, since the Jacobian is the Identity.

Please tell me if I could do a different change of variables or how I can get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobian is indeed 1, but you made a couple mistakes in your integral. We have $x'=x-1$, $y'=y-2$, $z'=z-3$, therefore $x=x'+1$, $y=y'+2$, $z=z'+3$. The integral becomes:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^4\int_0^{6-z'}\int_0^{5-y'-z'}(y'+2)\, dx\,dy\,dz
\end{equation}

You should get the same answer if you work this one out! :)

Comment: Oh right it should be $y'+2=y$!